# Can't read a name from a file if it is made of letters

Tags: python, file, python-2.x

Using VScode + code runner extension

Once `input()` function receives a string like "qwe", program returns "NameError: name "qwe" is not defined"
If input receives a string of numbers like "123", everything goes well.
All files exist in right directory,and named/formatted pretty fine. 
Example of function:

```
def maker():
    fileVar = str(input())
    fileVar = lineFixer(fileVar)
    with open(fileVar+".csv","r") as workfile:
        for line in workfile:
            return(line)
```

`lineFixer` is a dumb function for some cases (has no influence on result):

```
def lineFixer(line):
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.strip('\t')
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    line = line.replace('\t','')
    return line
```

Without `str(input())`, it's rubbish.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `input` takes everything a string.

Comment: files a mostly named like "result.csv" or "all.csv", and name of a file must be entered anytime fucntion goes on, no matter how the file named

Comment: What error are you getting? line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble that you are having is because you are using `input()` rather than `raw_input()`.

Modify your code to read `fileVar = raw_input()`

The difference between these two is that input is trying to evaluate your input as code. That's why you get the error with XYZ not being defined, it thinks it is a variable. Also, with using raw_input, you no longer should need the casting into a string with `str()`.

EDIT: I am assuming, since you have not specified this and from the error you are getting, that you are using Python2.X. In Python3, there should be only `input()`, working as `raw_input()`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ДжозефПристли No problem, glad to help. For the future, if you have questions about Python, it might be good to specify the version that you are using. Makes it much easier for others to help you :).